# Filter using a stream check inside a stream

Tags: java, java-8

The following program still prints `frank, jake, justin` and `persie` where in it should not include `justin` since he is blacklisted.

```
List<String> blacklists = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("mike", "ryan", "carl", "justin"));
List<String> names = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("frank", "jake", "justin", "persie"));

List<String> validatedNames = names.stream()
        .filter(name ->
            blacklists.stream()
                    .anyMatch(blacklist -> !blacklist.equals(name))
        )
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

validatedNames.forEach(name -> System.out.println(name));
```

Comment: `!blacklists.stream().anyMatch(blacklist -> blacklist.equals(name)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bug is on this line:

```
.anyMatch(blacklist -> !blacklist.equals(name))
```

Every name has some non-matching item in `blacklists`, therefore they all pass. You need to invert the condition like so:

```
.noneMatch(blacklist -> blacklist.equals(name))
```

But the whole inner stream is really unnecessary. Just use `List.contains()`:

```
List<String> validatedNames = names.stream()
        .filter(name -> !blacklists.contains(name))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you're willing to modify `names`, you can skip the stream altogether:

```
names.removeAll(blacklists);
```

Comment: Not only the inner stream is unnecessary. It’s also unnecessary to copy the `List` returned by `Arrays.asList` into an `ArrayList`, though, in the case of `blacklists`, it would make sense to copy it into a `HashSet` instead, to improve the performance of the predicate. The `removeAll` based solution can also be used without modifying `names`: `List<String> validatedNames = new ArrayList<>(names); validatedNames.removeAll(blacklists);`…